# How do I follow a link defined inside a jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a cucumber test (using Capybara) that needs to follow a link in a js.erb view.
The view looks like this:

```
  $('#form-or-login').html("<%= escape_javascript( link_to(image_tag("xxx", :border=>0), "yyy" )) %>");
```

How do I reach the link_to tag from my cucumber scenario?

```
And I follow [what goes here?]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having some non-visible text in the anchor as well. That way you could click it with capybara. Otherwise you will need to write a custom cucumber step for it.

Comment: Or instead of non-visible text (which I thought capybara won't interact with "non-visible" items), how about setting a title on the link?